# How to make Octave use "gnuplot" instead of "fltk" by default?

Tags: octave

I'm using Octave 3.8 on Ubuntu 13.10 and "fltk" for graphics is not working well. So I always switch to "gnuplot" by commanding:

```
graphics_toolkit("gnuplot")
```

How can I configure Octave to use "gnuplot" by default?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

You add the command to your `.octaverc` file.

For more info: http://www.gnu.org/software/octave/doc/interpreter/Startup-Files.html

Answer (score 9):

You can add that line to the `.octaverc` file. If the files does not exist, just create it on your home directory. This file is executed every time you start Octave unless you pass the `-f` or `--norc` option.

You can add many other things to you `.octaverc` file. As an example, this is part of mine:

```
## use man instead of help
function man (name = "help");
  mlock (); # lock in memory so it's not removed by clear all
  help (char (name));
endfunction

## no octave-core
crash_dumps_octave_core (0);

EDITOR ("nano");
edit ("mode", "sync");

## pretty prompt
PS1 ("\\[\\033[01;31m\\]\\s:\\#> \\[\\033[0m\\]");
## no > for multi-line input
PS2 ("");

## default image size to take the right half of the monitor
set (0,
  "DefaultFigurePosition",
    [get(0, "screensize")(3)/2    1 ...
     get(0, "screensize")(3)/2    get(0, "screensize")(4)]
);
```

Comment: That trick for images in the right half of the monitor is nice.